# How do you access OneSignal's database on Android & iOS in Flutter?

Tags: sqlite, flutter, onesignal

I am using OneSignal in my Flutter application to receive notifications. I have created my own table within Flutter to save notifications but I cannot save messages that have been sent whilst the app has been terminated. However, I have found that the OneSignal package has it's own database installed on the device which captures everything no matter what state the application is in! So, to avoid duplicating data I want to use this database instead. It is located outside of the flutter app folder which is my issue (see image below).

How do I access this database? Does anybody know if it is the same on iOS (I haven't been able to check at this time).

[image: OneSignal.db Android]

Many thanks.

Comment: Does this handler not work for you?, https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/flutter-sdk#section--setnotificationreceivedhandler-

Comment: @Ali123 yes but only when the app is in foreground or background. If the app has been terminated it does not fire

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's important to understand that if an app has been terminated, any onReceived handler will not be fired. We don't recommend using the local db at all. Your best bet is to use the respective notification extender services for each platform. Though you will have to write native code for this! Cheers

**Edit:**
ANDROID - NotificationExtenderService - This can be setup to receive silent notifications when your app is not running or to override how notifications are shown in the notification shade. See the [Background Data and Notification Overriding](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-customizations#section-background-data-and-notification-overriding) section to set this up.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Rodrigo and pointing me in the right direction. I've found the documentation on the OneSignal site. it would be really helpful if the information for notification extender services was linked on the Flutter SDK setup page, I can't imagine a scenario where a Flutter developer wouldn't want to have this functionality.

Comment: @F-1 Thanks for the recommendation. Just updated the documentation to reflect this